# Generic command-line argument parser with template, need implementation suggestion

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, command-line-arguments

I want to implement a C++ command line generic argument parser (also for fun). Existing popular argument parsers lack some functionalities.

- **gflags**: Does not support vector very well.
- **getopt**: C based, this is for without type.

I want a generic argument parser that can process arbitrary types, something like this:

```cpp
class YourArgument {
   vector<int> your_ints;
   string my_str;
   bool help;
};
YourArgument your_arg; 
Argparse(your_arg, argv, argc); // A template
```

This `Argparse` can process something like `"./run --help --my_str string --your_ints 1 2 3 run.txt"`.

I find something like C++17 structure binding can enable such implementation. If we are able to add some getters for a class, then we can implement it as follows.

```cpp
class YourArgument {
   vector<int> your_ints;
   string my_str;
   bool help;
   auto& get(integral_constant<int, 0>) { return your_ints; }
   auto& get(integral_constant<int, 1>) { return my_str; }
   auto& get(integral_constant<int, 2>) { return help; }
   const char* getstr(int i) {
       if (i == 0) return "your_ints";
       if (i == 1) return "my_str";
       if (i == 2) return "help";
   }
};

template <typename T>
void Argparse_impl(T& your_arg, const char **argv, int &argc, int &c) {
    // Common recursive implementation
    // Skipped here
    Argparse_impl<i+1>(your_arg, argv, argc, c);
}

template <typename T>
void Argparse(T& your_arg, const char **argv, int &argc) {
    int c = 0;
    while (c < argc) Argparse_impl<0>(your_arg, argv, argc, c);
}
```

The parser implementation itself is just a normal recursive tricks, which is not the part that I need suggestion. **My question is that is there any way to generate the boilerplate with macro?**

I have tried this implementation, the code roughly looks like this (not the exact code I used). However, it drastically lengthen my compile performance. I have lots of such classes to compile, and the structs are very long.

```
#define MY_MACRO(...)\
    auto& get_tuple() { return forward_as_tuple(__VA_ARGS_); }\
    template<unsigned i> auto& get() { return get<i>(get_tuple()); }\
    const char* getstr() { static string strs = string(##__VA_ARGS_).split(); return strs[i]; }\
```

Comment: Have a look at boost::program_options https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: Expanding macros should be dirt cheap. If anything lengthens your build times, that would be the templates themselves.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm afraid I don't have a suggestion on how to improve your solution, it seems the functionality that you are looking for is entirely possible without using macro's using C++ argparse library https://github.com/morrisfranken/argparse . It supports vectors and everything is represented in a struct. Here is an example of how you can use it for your example

```cpp
#include "argparse/argparse.hpp"

struct MyArgs : public argparse::Args {
    std::string &src_path     = arg("a positional string argument");
    int &k                    = kwarg("k", "A keyworded integer value");
    std::vector<int> &numbers = kwarg("n,numbers", "An optional vector of integers").multi_argument().set_default(std::vector<int>{1,2});
    bool &verbose             = flag("v,verbose", "A flag to toggle verbose");
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MyArgs args = argparse::parse<MyArgs>(argc, argv);

    // print all input numbers
    for (int &n : args.numbers)
         std::cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can run this example using:

```
./run source_path -k 1 --numbers 3 4 5
```

disclaimer: I'm the author of the library